# python strip string from end the most greedily

Tags: python, regex

here it is:

```
str_ = 'file_.csv_.csv.bz2'
re.sub(regex, '', str_)
```

I want 'regex' value to get `'file_.csv_'` i.e. the file name without the actual extension which here `'.csv.bz2'` and could be `'.csv.*'` while `.* = ''|bz2|gz|7z|`... any compression format.

More precisely I want `re.sub` to match from the end of `str_` the most greedily.
with `regex = '\.csv.*$'` I would get only `'file_'`.

I could of course do `os.path.splitext()` - check if `str_` ends with `'.csv'` - `os.path.splitext()` if so, but is there a shorter way?

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name, you are now masking the built-in type.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `re.split()` splitting of the suffix:

```
result = re.split(r'\.csv(?:\.\w+)?$', filename)[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> filename = 'file_.csv_.csv.bz2'
>>> re.split(r'\.csv(?:\.\w+)?$', filename)[0]
'file_.csv_'
>>> re.split(r'\.csv(?:\.\w+)?$', 'foobar_.csv_.csv')[0]
'foobar_.csv_'
>>> re.split(r'\.csv(?:\.\w+)?$', 'foobar_.csv_.csv.gz')[0]
'foobar_.csv_'
```

Comment: your second demo is showing that your solution does not do what I want. While 'foobar_.csv_.csv''s extension is '.csv', re.split()[0] should output 'foobar_.csv_'

Comment: @user1850133: my apologies, I intended to include a `?` and forgot.. Oops! Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

This would remove all the continuous extensions and prints only the filename,

```
>>> s = "file_.csv_.csv.bz2"
>>> m = re.sub(r'[.a-z0-9]+$', r'', s)
>>> m
'file_.csv_'
>>> s = "foobar_.csv_.csv.gz"
>>> m = re.sub(r'[.a-z0-9]+$', r'', s)
>>> m
'foobar_.csv_'
```